# Betfair Tcl login script

Tags: https, tcl, betfair

I'm trying to use the following tcl script to login into betfair non-interactively:-

```
#!/usr/bin/env tclsh
package require TclCurl

set postData "username=xxxxxxxxx&password=yyyyyyyyy"
set postHeader [list "X-Application: curlCommandLineTest"]
set BFLogin [::curl::transfer -url https://identitysso-cert.betfair.com/api/certlogin \
-headervar loginHeader \
-sslverifypeer 0 \
-sslcert "client-2048.crt" \
-sslkey "client-2048.key" \
-post 1 \
-postfields $postData \
-httpheader $postHeader ]
```

However, it's not storing the output in BFLogin. Instead when the script finishes it just outputs something like:-

```
{"sessionToken":"92YN1v2Oz0lVv59nHwCryrfCnzNbInTCsssssssssssssssssss","loginStatus":"SUCCESS"}
```

Which is fine but it's not storing it in the variable BFLogin above. What am I doing wrong please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I gathered from [this manual](https://manned.org/tclcurl/21536406) and the [wiki](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/TclCurl), it seems like you can use the option `-bodyvar` to tell curl where to store the body response (the call response and the body response are separate). I cannot test the code, but it should probably work like that:

```
#!/usr/bin/env tclsh
package require TclCurl

set postData "username=xxxxxxxxx&password=yyyyyyyyy"
set postHeader [list "X-Application: curlCommandLineTest"]
set responseBody ""
set BFLogin [::curl::transfer -url https://identitysso-cert.betfair.com/api/certlogin \
    -bodyvar responseBody \
    -sslverifypeer 0 \
    -sslcert "client-2048.crt" \
    -sslkey "client-2048.key" \
    -post 1 \
    -postfields $postData \
    -httpheader $postHeader ]
```

<sub>I also removed the headervar option you had, since it doesn't look like you were using it</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Possibly more readable?

```
#!/usr/bin/env tclsh
package require TclCurl

dict set curlOpts -url https://identitysso-cert.betfair.com/api/certlogin
dict set curlOpts -bodyvar responseBody
dict set curlOpts -sslverifypeer 0
dict set curlOpts -sslcert "client-2048.crt"
dict set curlOpts -sslkey "client-2048.key"
dict set curlOpts -post 1
dict set curlOpts -postfields "username=xxxxxxxxx&password=yyyyyyyyy"
dict set curlOpts -httpheader [list "X-Application: curlCommandLineTest"]

curl::transfer {*}$curlOpts
```